# Debugging after Setup and Deployment?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment

Can I still add to my application and debug it after I have done the Setup and Deployment on the project?

Comment: yes you can, but you need to rebuild the msi after u modify the code base

Comment: If I go to the Build menu and choose Rebuild will this rebuilt the MSI file as well?

Comment: Absolutely. Choose RebuildAll (or BuildAll or whatever that is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you will be able to `Debug` your application only if you have built your assemblies in `Debug` mode. `Release` mode assemblies will not contain information required for debugging and hence you will not be able to debug it.

Also if you are trying to debug remotely, you should read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx)

One more point : The deployed code should be available with you (may be you have already 'tagged' it) to be able to debug the application. If you have modified code after deployment, you may not be able to reproduce / find issues, which you will see when using your application.

Hope I am clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can just write this code `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();`